# Tridion Security issue after renaming Machine Name

Tags: tridion

We installed Tridion on our servers and after the installation we changed the user name, after which we have been seeing this issue in our logs:

```
Access is denied for the user MYMachinename\MTSUser.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 770
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, String impersonationUserName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String userName, String impersonationUserName, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Impersonate(String userName)
   at SyncInvokeImpersonate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Answer (score 7):

I assume you changed the name of MTSUser.

You will need to update it in a few places then:

1. The TRUSTEES table in the database.
2. The Identity tab on the "SDL Tridion Content Manager" package in Component Services.
3. On any Tridion services you have that run as the MTSUser.
4. Various places in your Tridion Content Manager Configuration (e.g. Search settings -> Query Engine Settings / Indexer Service Settings)

Your Windows security settings should be fine, though, if you just renamed the user.

I might have forgotten some places, in which case I'm sure people will chime in.

Worst case scenario, you have to reinstall/repair - which might actually end up being the easiest option :)

Comment: Not typical of enterprise setups which have separate servers for the database, but for "all-in-one" dev or training setups, you may need to update the [Tridion Content Manager MMC Snap-in settings for the `Database server name`](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3560/46).

Answer (score 4):

The errors you have after renaming can be caused by:

- You need to update the account configured on the "**SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+**" properties, inside the identity tab (Your error looks like this one to me)

[image]

- **License**: Depending on your license it can be coupled to a Machine Name. You will need to check with customer support for this.
- Trustees table on the database will need to be updated. You may want to discuss it with customer support before any manual change on the database

Comment: I did change the com+ application and the Trustee table but that did not resolve my issue.